# How to use createCustomVideoTrack to deliver a composite image in canvas

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying to deliver a video and image composite to canvas in the web version of Agora. In layman's terms, it's a virtual background.
I was able to do it to some extent, but the background of the remote image is black. I would appreciate it if you could point out what seems to be missing to make the background an image.
In addition, the local video is a virtual background as I expected. When viewed on the remote, there is no background.
Environment used: JavaScript, chrome latest version, uploaded to server for viewing.

2021/03/19　I'm sorry for the delay, but I'm attaching the code.

```js
async function virtual($video,$destCanvas,net) {

 // THESE LINES ARE REQUIRED!
  $video.width = $destCanvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
  $video.height = $destCanvas.height = $video.videoHeight;

  const destCtx = $destCanvas.getContext("2d");
  $destCanvas.style.backgroundImage = "url(vvv.png)";
  $destCanvas.style.backgroundSize = "contain";

  // to remove background, need another canvas

  $tempCanvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
  $tempCanvas.height = $video.videoHeight;
  const tempCtx = $tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
 
  (async function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    // create mask on temp canvas
    const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson($video);
    const mask = bodyPix.toMask(segmentation);
    tempCtx.putImageData(mask, 0, 0);

    // draw original
    destCtx.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $destCanvas.width, $destCanvas.height);

    // then overwrap, masked area will be removed
    destCtx.save();
    destCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    
    destCtx.drawImage($tempCanvas, 0, 0, $destCanvas.width, $destCanvas.height);

    destCtx.restore();
    xxxCanvas = $destCanvas;

  })();
};
async function join() {
  // create Agora client

  rtc.client.setClientRole(options.role);

  if (options.role === "audience") {
    // add event listener to play remote tracks when remote user publishs.
    rtc.client.on("user-published", handleUserPublished);
    rtc.client.on("user-unpublished", handleUserUnpublished);
    $("#leave").attr("disabled", false);
  }

  // join the channel
  options.uid = await rtc.client.join(options.appid, options.channel, options.token || null);

  if (options.role === "host") {

    hostRole();

    console.log("publish success");
    $("#leave").attr("disabled", false);

  }
}

async function hostRole(){
 
    const MediaStream = xxxCanvas.captureStream();
    
    localTracks.audioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({ microphoneId : getSelectedAudio(),encoderConfig: "high_quality_stereo"});
    localTracks.videoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack({ cameraId : getSelectedVideo()});
    
    await rtc.client.publish([
      
     AgoraRTC.createCustomVideoTrack({

      mediaStreamTrack: MediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0],
      })
     , localTracks.audioTrack]);   
}
```

Comment: Please update the question to include any code that you have tried.

Comment: The code has been added.

Comment: There was an announcement that a beta version of virtual backgrounds will be implemented in late May 2021!